# React native reload a page when pressing a button

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi I'm building an app with react native (using expo). When users press a button (a TouchableOpacity one) I want to call a function that add a record in the database (this part works perfectly) and then reload the page (the Component). I can't find a solution on how to reload the Component. I tried forceUpadate() but it didn't work

Here is my code

```
class Screen extends Component {
      .
      . 
      .
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.style}
    onPress={() => {      
    this.func(param1,param2),
    alert("Something"),               
    //Reload the component
    // I tried this.forceUpdat() but didn't work
    }}
 >
   <Text> ... </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
       .
       .
       .
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by database?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in the same problem then i figured it out that you just need Hooks or useState to resolve the refresh issue. In my case of refreshing random deck

```
    const [random1, setRandom1] = useState(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length) + 1
    );

    <Image source={deck[random1]} style={styles.img} />

    <Button
    title="Refresh?"
    onPress={() => {
      setRandom1(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length) + 1);
    }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

By "reload the Component" if you mean refresh the content of the component, you'll need to render the content with component state.
After that, use setState to update the component's state. The content should automatically update in the next render.

If you could provide some more detail, I could modify it to elaborate.

In the mean time, please read [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) to see some examples of using component state.